# HTML form inputs field and sends data from ssms db via node,express

Tags: node.js, sql-server, forms, express

I have created a database in SSMS having tables like Products, Subcategories and Categories. I am able to execute queries on SSMS and also able to connect it to node js. Now I want to create a form that asks for category name as a drop down list and on submitting the form I should get a table containing all the products that belong to the specified category.

I have tried using express but the desired output is not shown

The HTML file is:

```
<!-- form.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Product Display</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Select a Category</h1>

  <form id="categoryForm" action="/submit-form" method="post">
    <label for="category">Choose a category:</label>
    <select id="category" name="category">
      <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
      <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
      <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
    </select>
   
    <button type="button" onclick="fetchAndDisplay()">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    function fetchAndDisplay() {
      const form = document.getElementById('categoryForm');
      const formData = new FormData(form);

      fetch('/submit-form', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
        resultDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>Products in the selected category:</h2>';

        if (data.length === 0) {
          resultDiv.innerHTML += '<p>No products found.</p>';
        } else {
          resultDiv.innerHTML += '<ul>';
          data.forEach(product => {
            resultDiv.innerHTML+=`<li>${product.product_name} (Category: ${product.category_name})</li>`;
          });
          resultDiv.innerHTML += '</ul>';
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the server file is as app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sqlConfig = {
  user: '',
  password: '',
  server: '',
  database: '',
  options: {
    encrypt: false,  \\i am not using Azure 
  },
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/form.html');
});

app.post('/submit-form', async (req, res) => {
  const selectedCategory = req.body.category;

  try {
    await sql.connect(sqlConfig);

    const result = await sql.query(`
      SELECT p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.Price,c.CategoryName,s.SubcategoryName 
      FROM Products p
      INNER JOIN SubCategories s ON p.SubcategoryID=s.SubcategoryID
      INNER JOIN Categories c ON s.CategoryID=c.CategoryID
      WHERE c.CategoryName= '${selectedCategory}'
    `);

    await sql.close();

    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

On running the above by node app.js I am getting an empty [] object. Could anyone point out what is wrong here?

I have deliberately not written details about the config object but those are also alright. By what i have understood I think the paths and methods are working ok. previously I had tried printing JSON format on the browser by writing a query and it works fine as:

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');

const app = express();

// Configuration for your SQL Server database
const config = {
    user: '',
    password: '',
    server: '',  // Update with your SQL Server address
    database: '',  // Update with your database name
    options: {
        encrypt: false,  // Set to true if your SQL Server uses SSL
    },
};

app.get('/categories', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Create a pool of connections
        const pool = await sql.connect(config);

        // Query to select data from a table (replace 'YourTable' with your actual table name)
        //const q = 'SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE CategoryName = \'electronics\'';
        const q='SELECT * FROM Products';
        const result = await pool.request().query(q);

        // Send the result as JSON to the browser
        res.json(result.recordset);

        // Close the connection pool
        await pool.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: You need to debug your app and find out exactshich step is failing .

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data to the server in `multipart/form-data` format, but you don't have middleware on the server to process it (for example, [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), so, the `selectedCategory` parameter from `req.body` is undefined (also, you should [use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection)).

Multipart is usually needed to post files, but as you're not posting files, you could send JSON request instead (`express.json()` middleware will process it).

You can still utilize `FormData`: convert the `FormData` object constructed from HTML form to JSON:

```
const data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
```

and then send it as a JSON format:

```
const formData = new FormData(form);

const data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

// or one-liner
//const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
    
fetch('/submit-form', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

To prevent `form` to reload page on submit, pass the `event` to the submit handler and then prevent default behaviour:

```
<button type="button" onclick="fetchAndDisplay(event)">Submit</button>
```

```
function fetchAndDisplay(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

However, [the use of event handler content attributes is discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes), so, you could replace button onclick by adding `submit` listener to the form, and use `fetchAndDisplay` as a handler:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

```
const form = document.getElementById('categoryForm');

function fetchAndDisplay(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //..
}

form.addEventListener('submit', fetchAndDisplay);
```

Also, on the server, you could add error handler that makes sure all parameters are provided, for example:

```
if(!selectedCategory) return res.status(400).json({msg:'Missing category'});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried going through the code again and based on my understanding, the results and query are working fine but the response is not reflected in the <div id='result'>. What i wanted was to ask for category in the form and show the form results just below it and not go to some other page. Will react be a better option to implement this? I am new to web dev and have no prior experience

Comment: ah, yes, the HTML form reloads the page. add `event.preventDefault();` to the handler, see the updated code